# ADB not in my task manager process

Tags: android, sdk, adb, adt

I've download an ADT bundle and I've installed the versions of API that I needed. However, I do have the adb.exe in my adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools/ folder, however, it is not in my task manager, and because of that, I can't seems to run my program, is there anything i could do? I had tried re-installing everything from scratch, still doesn't work

[image: adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools folder]

[image: task manager]

Comment: you just try to run your android application from adt and adb.exe will be automatically started..

Comment: i can't start my application ):

Comment: why arent you not able to start?? i mean..any error???

Comment: it seems like i dont have adb.exe.. lol

Answer (score 1):

While adb is an exe I'm not sure it opens properly by double clicking.(I use OSX)  adb is an acronym for android debug bridge.  It is a console program that might be better accessed using the shell to get into it.  This is not the same thing as an emulator.  This is instead a program that allows you to shell into your device to view or change files in the app. Also remember that once you are in the adb that android is Linux and you will be using bash to communicate with the device.

Comment: i double clicked it, but an command prompt showed up for a moment (with long of stuff being loaded) and gone

Comment: Here is a list of Windows shell commands. You will need to open the shell in windows and either type run and follow that with the path and program to execute, or go to the directory using the cd command followed by the path and then type run and then type in adb.exe http://ss64.com/nt/